# Projective geometry well defined bijection

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry, projective-space, affine-geometry

I consider the sphere $\mathbb S^n:=\{x\in\mathbb R^{n+1}: \|x\|=1 \}$ and the equivalence relation $x\sim y:\Leftrightarrow x=\pm y$.

How can it be shown that the inclusion $\mathbb S^n\rightarrow\mathbb R^{n+1}$ induces a well-defined bijection $\mathbb S^n/\sim\rightarrow\mathbb {RP}^n$ ?

If I could show that I would get the identification $\mathbb{ RP}^2=\mathbb S^2/\sim$, i.e the points of the projective plane $\mathbb {RP}^2$ can be identified with the antipodal points on $\mathbb S^2$.

My second question is, how can the projective lines in this image be described?

Comment: $\mathbb R\mathbb P^n$ is $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ modulo scalar multiplication and $\pm1$ are among the scalars.

Comment: Thanks I just noticed that $[\lambda x_0:...:\lambda x_n]$ lies in the unit sphere iff $|\lambda|=1$ but I still do not see the bijection. What is meant with the projective lines in this image?

Comment: Is the problem with "well-defined" or with "bijection"? All parts follow quickly from the definition of injective/surjective and just picking elements. If two points on the sphere map to the same class, then they differ by a scalar multiple, which you've pointed out must be $\pm 1$ and hence they are the same class in $S^n/\sim$. Surjective: pick a class, then by rescaling any representative you can make it on the sphere (of unit length).

Comment: Thanks, may you could explain the surjective part a little bit more in detail, I know exactly what you mean but do not write do write it down formally. Do you also have an idea what is meant with projective lines in this image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested. To prove surjectivity, suppose we have an arbitrary element $[x_0: \cdots : x_n]\in \mathbb{RP}^n$. We must find some element $y\in S^n/\sim$ that maps to it.

Since some $x_i\neq 0$, we have $\|(x_0, \ldots, x_n)\|\neq 0$ and hence $\displaystyle y=\frac{(x_0, \ldots, x_n)}{\|(x_0, \ldots, x_n)\|}\in S^n$.

The map in question is including this into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ followed by the quotient map, i.e. $y\mapsto [y]$. But now $[y]=[x_0: \cdots : x_n]$ because $y$ is just a scalar multiple of $(x_0, \ldots , x_n)$.

There are several equivalent ways of describing/thinking about lines. I noticed [Lines in projective space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139085/lines-in-projective-space?rq=1) off to the right, and Georges answer is exactly how I'd describe it.